# What happen to my pi

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, boot

I standby for 8 hour and shutdown. Can't open why?

Sorry for my english.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Pi won't start because the boot sequence is unable to mount your root file system. This might be due to a misconfiguration or possibly a corrupt SD-card.

Answer (score 0):

I would lean more towards the SD Card being corrupt in this case. If it was an issue with the actual OS I would have suspected more of a clear indication that no OS or something found or more direction in terms of error message.